# Paypal IPN & updating database dilemma

Tags: php, html, sql, paypal, paypal-ipn

So I have a problem and dont know what way to approach it. What I am trying to do so when the user verifies there email they are directed to a page where they select the membership plan and then they are directed to paypal to proceed with the payment - the payment field in the DB is then updated. They are then redirecting back to the website.

**Problem 1:** I have PayPal IPN PHP page witch is so-pose to handle the problem but that does not seem to be working or not even being called i dont know. I do have the ipn enabled and configured in the PayPal acount

```html
<?php

// STEP 1: Read POST data

// reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
// issues with array data in POST
// reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 


$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'); // change to [...]sandbox.paypal[...] when using sandbox to test
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    if ($_POST['mc_gross'] != NULL)
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    else
           $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross1'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $custom = $_POST['custom'];

    
    
    // Insert your actions here

    include 'base.php';

    $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE EMAIL ='$email'";

    //Run Query 
    $result = $link->query($q) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

    //Numbers  of rows that match
    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;


    if($num_rows > 0){

       $query = "UPDATE 'users' SET 'payment' ='$payment_amount' WHERE EMAIL ='$payer_email'";
       $link->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

       if($link){
          echo "<script>console.log( 'success '');</script>";
     
       }
    }else{
      
    }
  
?>
```

**Problem 2** Even if this wont there be a problem is the user used someone else account for a different email.

If any one had the patients to stick with me a read this far thanks, Any help would be great.

Regards
Amy

Comment: Any time I'm ever working with IPN I like to follow these steps:  https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/.  That will allow you to see things working, and then test against the PayPal sandbox after that.  Once you're at that point you know it'll work the same way live.

Comment: @AndrewAngell thanks for your help . Appreciate it